# How can I tell CMake to put include directory flags after the compiler option flags in its object compile command?

Tags: cmake, build, include-path, ninja, compileoptions

I am facing problems due to the target holding the include paths first and then the compiler options after. How can I set the include paths after the compiler options for compiling source files of a target?

My CMakeLists.txt file:

```
project(HelloWorld)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
add_library(HELLO_WORLD_LIB
                STATIC
                src/helloWorld.cpp
    )
target_include_directories(
            HELLO_WORLD_LIB AFTER PUBLIC D:\\temp\\includes 
        )
target_compile_options(HELLO_WORLD_LIB BEFORE PUBLIC -cpp -remap)
set_target_properties(HELLO_WORLD_LIB
        PROPERTIES
            OUTPUT_NAME hello
            ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  D:\\temp\\CMakeHelloWorld
            SUFFIX .a
    )
```

My cmake call:

```
call cmake -GNinja -S ./.. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../_bin
call cmake --build . --config Debug --verbose -d keeprsp
call cmake --install .
```

The console output:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/temp/CMakeHelloWorld/_build
[1/2] C:\mingw\test25_comp_8.1.0_testversion\bin\c++.exe -ID:/temp/includes -cpp -remap -MD -MT CMakeFiles/HELLO_WORLD_LIB.dir/src/helloWorld.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\HELLO_WORLD_LIB.dir\src\helloWorld.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/HELLO_WORLD_LIB.dir/src/helloWorld.cpp.obj -c ../src/helloWorld.cpp
[2/2] cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\cmake\.8-3.20.2\bin\cmake.exe -E rm -f ..\libhello.a && C:\mingw\test25_comp_8.1.0_testversion\bin\ar.exe qc ..\libhello.a  CMakeFiles/HELLO_WORLD_LIB.dir/src/helloWorld.cpp.obj && C:\mingw\test25_comp_8.1.0_testversion\bin\ranlib.exe ..\libhello.a && cd ."
-- Install configuration: ""
```

However if I try to add the include paths after compiler options, it sits before the compiler options. How can I set the compiler options before the include directories? like `C:\mingw\test25_comp_8.1.0_testversion\bin\c++.exe -cpp -remap -ID:/temp/includes`.

Comment: why do you want this? what difference does it make to how things get compiled? what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: somewhat related: [How can I remove an option from the default compile command template for a specific compiler?](/q/75292327)

Comment: the problem is compiler throws an error "fatal error : cannot open source file "xxx.h", due to include paths present before compiler options. if I make it include paths after compiler options this is not happening and compilation through....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant CMake variable is [`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OBJECT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILE_OBJECT.html), which is the configuration point for what template to use for the command to compile an object. The default value is set in `Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake`, and overrides are specified in various `Modules/Platform/*` or `Modules/Compiler/*` files. If you're curious, you can grep for the overrides with the following regex: `set.*CXX_COMPILE_OBJECT`.

The default one is set like this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OBJECT
  "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> <DEFINES> <INCLUDES> <FLAGS> -o <OBJECT> -c <SOURCE>")
```

You probably want something like this (set it in your own CMakeLists.txt file, or in [a toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html)):

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OBJECT
  "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> <DEFINES> <FLAGS> <INCLUDES> -o <OBJECT> -c <SOURCE>")
```

As far as I can tell, this configuration point is "global". I'm not aware of how to specify it with different values for different targets or source files.

---

If you're working with the Ninja generator and need this kind of change to affect the generated [.rsp files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-response-files), I think you'd need to build a modified version of CMake from source, since that behaviour seems to be baked into the binaries instead of CMake script files in the `Modules/` directory. The relecant source file is [`Source/cmNinjaTargetGenerator.cxx`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmNinjaTargetGenerator.cxx). Look at the lines of code that do `rule.RspContent =` and you'll see:

```
rule.RspContent =
  cmStrCat(' ', scanVars.Defines, ' ', scanVars.Includes, ' ', scanFlags);
```

You'd probably need to switch the order of `scanVars.Includes` and `scanVars.scanFlags`.

If you choose to make a modified CMake binary, as always, make sure you comply with [the software licence](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Copyright.txt).